# How to expose local variables with Polymer 1.0 dom-bind

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I've created a polymer element that needs a canvas 2d context as attribute to work, and I'm trying to get it from a sibling canvas tag.

I've seen https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html, but it doesn't answer my issue.

Here is what I have done for now:

```js
<body>
<template id="app" is="dom-bind">
    <my-element id="renderer" context="{{ context }}"></my-element>
    <canvas id="rendering-canvas"></canvas>
</template>
<script>
    (function (document) {
        'use strict';
        var app = document.querySelector('#app');

        app.addEventListener('template-bound', function () {
            console.log('Our app is ready to rock!');
        });

        window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function () {
            document.querySelector('body').removeAttribute('unresolved');

            var renderer = document.querySelector('my-element[id=renderer]'),
                canvas = document.querySelector('canvas[id=rendering-canvas]');

            app.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        });
    })(document);
</script>
</body>
```

Edit: MyElement

```
Polymer({
        is : 'my-element',
        properties: {
            type: {
                type: String,
                value: 'Text'
            },
            context: {
                type: CanvasRenderingContext2D
            }
        }
    });
```

My main issue is how to to something like `context="canvas.getContext('2d')"` ? Right now the my-element's context property is not set.

Comment: Hi! @FXG who is context in your question (context="canvas.getContext('2d')? I'm using your code and my app.context is CanvasRenderingContext2D {}. Is not correct?

Comment: Also my-element.context is same (CanvasRenderingContext2D).

Comment: @horacioibrahim Yes, but this context is not passed as an attribute of my "my-element". I will edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: Polymer lists the following available types for properties: `Boolean, Date, Number, String, Array or Object`. So, I don't think that's going to work the way you have it currently. Maybe `Object` will work?

Comment: I've found it, it was a problem on my-element side. Changes to context property wasn't reflected because attributes using it was created on ready function. I've created an observer method and apply my changes here. It's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<my-element id="renderer"></my-element>
<canvas id="rendering-canvas"></canvas>

<script>
    (function (document) {
        'use strict';

        window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function () {
            document.querySelector('body').removeAttribute('unresolved');

            var renderer = document.getElementById('renderer'),
                canvas = document.getElementById('rendering-canvas');

            renderer.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        });
    })(document);
</script>
```